# Nginx: Parameter not taken into account on a specific link structure

Tags: php, nginx, request

I have WP installed on my VPS (with nginx 1.3.12 and php5-fpm 5.4.11).

The first page of search results (/?s=test) is loaded properly, but
/page/2/?s=test displays the same content of /page/2/ (so ?s=test isn't
taken into account).

It's probably something wrong with my nginx config:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
try_files $uri =404;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

location / {
# if you're just using wordpress and don't want extra rewrites
# then replace the word @rewrites with  /index.php
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

}
```

Articles work fine anyway.. the permalink structure
(/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/) works fine.. so I should find a fix
that doesn't break that (but "fixes" the search parameter problem).

"DEMO"

Page 1 (/?s=test): http://goo.gl/HigKa

Page 2 (/page/2/?s=test): http://goo.gl/ujftR

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved changing the location block with this:

```
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
```